# Georeferenced Tiffs displaying in the wrong location & scale when updating ArcGIS 10

Tags: geotiff-tiff, georeferencing

I'm working on a project which involves georeferencing a large number of .tiff files to digitize data from them. All the tiffs which have already be georeferenced where done with ArcMap 10.0 without any service packs installed. In an effort to solve an issue with the pixels inverting and a certain zoom level, I've been experimenting with upgrading service packs. Each service pack I install causes some, but not all, of the previously georeferenced tiff files to display at a significantly smaller size, and in the incorrect location. The location change may just be do the the scaling problem though, since it is still near the correct location, I'm not positive though. Also, when I open the same map document on the other computer in the office running ArcMap 10.0 without any service packs, the tiffs are located where they should be and the proper size. I'm currently running ArcMap 10.0 with Service Pack 5 installed, and I've also installed the [Raster Format Patch](http://support.esri.com/en/downloads/patches-servicepacks/view/productid/160/metaid/1648#updates), neither of which have helped. I've done a few searches, and have not been able to find any solutions for this issue. Has anyone else run into this problem?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Are the incorrect tifs aligned to 0,0 or do they retain some (wrong) georeferencing information?  It may be best to just rectify the images on the unpatched machine.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same (i guess) when i zoomed under 1:300000 the raster is fine above 1:300000 the pixel size turned larger. I thik that the problem was in the pyramid generation.

So, what i did was generate another tif using the "image station raster utilities" and insert the new raster into arcmap. With that a new *.ovr file was generated solving the initial issue.

Hope this is helpfull.